# Reading last line of a file

Tags: c++, objective-c, file-io

I have a large file and I need to get only the last line from it (`\n` only is the line separator).
I need this to be done on iOS device, so it cannot take much memory or cpu time (like reading the whole file).
How can I do this in either Objective-C,c++ or c++11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the feature in my production code.The idea is that try to read the last line by seeking and reading.Take a look please.

```
bool readLastLine(std::string const& filename, std::string& lastLine)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename.c_str(),std::ifstream::binary);
    if(!in) return false;
    in.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
    const std::streamoff len = in.tellg();
    //empty file
    if(len == 0)
    {
        lastLine = "";
        return true;
    }
    int buf_size = 128;
    std::vector<char> buf;
    while(in)
    {   
        if(buf_size > len)
        {
            buf_size = len;
        }
        buf.resize(buf_size);
        in.seekg(0 - buf_size, std::ifstream::end);
        in.read(&buf[0],buf_size);
        //all content is in the buffer or we already have the complete last line
        if(len == buf_size || std::count(buf.begin(), buf.end(), '\n') > 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        //try enlarge the buffer
        buf_size *= 2;
    }
    //find the second line seperator from the end if any
    auto i = std::find(++buf.rbegin(),buf.rend(), '\n');
    lastLine.assign(i == buf.rend() ?  buf.begin() : buf.begin() + std::distance(i, buf.rend()), buf.begin() + buf_size);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have a problem here that you read the end several times, and look in it several times for end lines when it's no neccesery - you already read it and you know it has no new lines.

Comment: @Dani you could make any optimization. For most cases, as long as the length of last line is smaller than 128, we read the last line only once. I could change the default buffer size to 512. It works in my product.

Answer (score 5):

Conceptually I think you'd want to open the file and seek the whole way to the end minus N bytes (maybe 80 or something).  Then read that and look for the \n.  If you don't find it, then seek N bytes earlier and try it on that set of N bytes, and so on until you find the \n.

As for the specific calls, that's just a matter of looking up how to open a file, seek around in it, and read data.  Should be pretty straightforward.  But I think the above is what you'd want to do and pick a size for N which isn't too large.

Comment: does N = 80 have any advantage over N = 1?

Comment: Yes, seeks can be slow, while reading in several is almost the same speed as reading in one.

Answer (score 2):

@Nerdtron answer seems the most appropriate to me, if you don't have a control over your file format, but...

If you have a control over the file format, you may do this with O(1) complexity. Simply write the offset of the start of the last line to a (constant) offset in the beginning of your file when you write the data to it. When you want to read it, read this offset, and go to the specified offset in it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, trying to improve on Bruce, the upside is the buffer doesn't need resizing, just keep reading same-sized chunks of characters ever farther from the EOF:

```
std::string lastLine(std::ifstream &file)
{
    if (!file.good()) throw exception("Bad stream on input");

    const size_t bufSize = 80; // because why not? tweak if need to
    char buf[bufSize];
    string line;

    int seek, nloff;
    // iterate over multiples of bufSize while file ok
    for (size_t n = 1; file; ++n)
    {
        // next seek position will be a multiple of bufSize
        seek = -static_cast<int>(n * bufSize);
        file.seekg(seek, file.end);
        // read "bufSize" bytes into buffer
        file.read(buf, bufSize);

        // in case no newline found, seek past eof
        nloff = -seek;
        // find offset of last newline in buffer
        for (size_t i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i)
        {
            if (buf[i] == '\n') nloff = i;
        }
        seek += nloff + 1; // new seek position is one character after found newline
        if (seek >= 0) continue; // just kidding about the "past eof" part ;)

        // seek to after found newline and get line
        file.seekg(seek, file.end);
        getline(file, line);
        if (!line.empty()) break; // have result, break and return
    }

    if (file.good()) return line;
    else return string();
}
```